# Dealing with no data in a dataset used to develop a shiny application (shiny, leaflet, R studio). error : subscript out of bounds

Tags: shiny, mapping, leaflet

When the dataset that I use in the shiny application  has no data an error appears: subscript out of bounds - and the app stays blank, without my map. I want that even when the error occurs, the map appears but with any marker. How can I do this?

Hi, I am using R shiny and leaflet to develop an application that gives a map with markers and each time that I click on a marker, a table with information about that specific marker appears. Also I have a side bar developed through if/else statements so I can search the information that I want. Explaining, I can search information about a specific year, a period of that year, a specific condition and the status for that condition. 
Everything runs fine, but the only problem is dealing with missing information in my dataset (I don’t have data for a specific period of a year). When I don’t have data an error in shiny occurs “subscript out of bounds”. I want that in addition of that, the map appears but without markers. So, only the simple map. I already have developed if and else statements but they are not successful. How can I keep the map even when a shiny error occurs?
Is something that I need to change in the server? Or UI?

Server code:

```
pal <- colorFactor(c("lawngreen", "red", "darkgray", "yellow", "orange"), 
                   domain = c("Confirmed negative", "Confirmed positive", "Don't know", "Likely negative", "Likely positive"))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    data_for_map <- reactive({
    if (input$disease_choice != "All") {
      if (input$disease_quarter != "All") {
        if (input$disease_status != "All") {
          data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
            filter(disease == input$disease_choice, status == input$disease_status,
                   quarter == input$disease_quarter, year == input$disease_year)
        } else {
          data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
            filter(disease == input$disease_choice, quarter == input$disease_quarter, year == input$disease_year)
        }
      } else { 
        if (input$disease_status != "All") {
          data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
            filter(disease == input$disease_choice, status == input$disease_status, year == input$disease_year)
        } else {
          data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
            filter(disease == input$disease_choice, year == input$disease_year)
        }
      }
      } else {
        if (input$disease_quarter != "All") {
          if (input$disease_status != "All") {
            data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
                filter(status == input$disease_status, quarter == input$disease_quarter, year == input$disease_year)
            } else {
              data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
                filter(quarter == input$disease_quarter, year == input$disease_year)
            }
          } else {
            if (input$disease_status != "All") {
              data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
                filter(status == input$disease_status, year == input$disease_year)
            } else {
              data_to_plot <- pig_data_long %>%
                filter(year == input$disease_year)
            }
          }
      }

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet("map") %>%
      setView(lng = -3.64, lat = 57.36, zoom = 7) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = data_for_map()[[2]],
                       radius = 4,
                       color = "black",
                       stroke = FALSE,
                       fillOpacity = 1,
                       popup = ~(slapmark)) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = data_for_map()[[1]], 
                       color = ~pal(status),
                       stroke = FALSE,
                       fillOpacity = 1,
                       popup = ~(paste(quarter, disease, status, sep = ": ")),
                       layerId = ~(paste(slapmark, disease, status, sep = "-"))) %>%
      addLegend("bottomright",
                colors = c("lawngreen", "yellow", "orange", "red", "darkgray"), 
                labels = c("Confirmed negative", "Likely negative", "Likely positive", "Confirmed positive", "Don't know"),
                title = "Legend",
                labFormat = labelFormat(),
                opacity = 1) 

  })

 output$clicked = DT::renderDataTable({
    point = input$map_marker_click
    if (!is.null(point)) {
      point_slapmark = strsplit(point$id, "-") [[1]][1]
      data_for_map()[[1]] %>%
        filter(slapmark == point_slapmark) %>%
        select(-latitude, -longitude) %>%
        DT::datatable(data_for_map, options = list(dom = 'ltipr'),
                      class = "display", callback = JS("return table;"),
                      style = "default")
    }
  }) 
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a simple map object, and just set the view like below..

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({ 
  leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = -3.64, lat = 57.36, zoom = 7)
})
```

Then use the leafletProxy() function in side an observe() to add markers etc after validating your data, e.g..

```
leafletProxy("map")  %>%
   addTiles() %>%
   addCircleMarkers(data = data_for_map()[[2]],
                   radius = 4,
                   color = "black",
                   stroke = FALSE,
                   fillOpacity = 1,
                   popup = ~(slapmark)) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = data_for_map()[[1]], 
                   color = ~pal(status),
                   stroke = FALSE,
                   fillOpacity = 1,
                   popup = ~(paste(quarter, disease, status, sep = ": ")),
                   layerId = ~(paste(slapmark, disease, status, sep = "-"))) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright",
            colors = c("lawngreen", "yellow", "orange", "red", "darkgray"), 
            labels = c("Confirmed negative", "Likely negative", "Likely positive", "Confirmed positive", "Don't know"),
            title = "Legend",
            labFormat = labelFormat(),
            opacity = 1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help! It is not working... and I don't know if I really need to use leafletproxy.. I want to say to shiny.. "when the error occur and appears "subscript out of bounds" run a basic map"